# Chess middle game puzzle online for free

Tags: strategy, puzzles, middlegame, websites

Recently, I was looking for a website where I can find only middle game puzzles. I found [the website](https://chessfox.com/chess-puzzles-for-intermediate-players/), I had solved most of the puzzles in less than a minute (If I get enough time, I can solve any puzzles between 0-1700 (If I rush little bit I make mistakes even in 700, for that reason I am gonna call myself not-speedy-player)). Anyway, I was thinking of improving "my thinking knowledge", by doing chess puzzles as I did for tactics. When I play a game in online, I feel like, my opponent is playing too fast, so I have to unless I will lose on time. That's why I am planning to play middle game puzzles. And when I read Silman's book, sometimes I feel like I am at 1800+ rated player (There's also another reason, I can beat upto 2000 rating bot in chess.com average time). But, I am too lazy to memorize more than 8 moves (using Board also works, but I read it at night in dark room).

**Is there a website where I can freely play middle game puzzles?** There's currently two sites I know, lichess and chess.com. I already have 2000 ratings in puzzle in an account in chess.com but the fact is I can't afford membership. There's also a reason why I can't play puzzles in lichess. Default puzzles rating is too low and I can solve them but I get tired after getting around 100 ratings and lose 200 ratings. And I don't get that much of time to solve tactics. But I will be happy if I can do 5-10 puzzles in a day. FYI, I had found a website around 5-6 months ago where I could choose options for different type (openings, middle-game, endgame). I was bad at tactics that's why I stopped solving problem there. And after reinstallation of my OS I lost that history. That's why I am sure that there's an website on middle-game puzzle (the website's design was poorly developed so it's not SEO. I can't find by quick internet search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lichess is completely free and offers middlegame puzzles: https://lichess.org/training/middlegame .

Answer (score 2):

The site you used was most likely [Chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com), one of the greatest sites for training. It's even one of the most innovative (see endgame puzzles or technology similar to chessables Move-Trainer), despite its design, which looks like it was from 15 years ago...
You get unlimited free chess tactics, but only 2 free endgame puzzles in a day.